# In a macOS Cocoa Document-Based Application what could be a good implementation strategy for a "New From Template" feature like for example in Logic?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-data, nsdocument

Thanks in advance for your help. I have a good experience on macOS applications, but I am almost new in regard to document-based apps. I am trying with a new project that is document-based and uses CoreData. I would like to implement a "New Document From Template" so that when choosing a certain template, the application creates a New Document with some core data objects created and populated in the document's managed object context. What could be a clean approach to achieve this ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`NSDocumentController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocumentcontroller)'s [`duplicateDocument(withContentsOf:copying:displayName:)` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocumentcontroller/1514982-duplicatedocument):

> Creates a new document by reading the contents for the document from another URL, presents its user interface, and returns the document if successful.

You'll want to call it like this:

```
let document = try NSDocumentController.shared.duplicateDocument(
    withContentsOf: templateUrl,
    copying: true,
    displayName: "Untitled")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Fits the purpose perfectly ! Furthermore, you can cast the document as your NSDocument or NSPersistentDocument subclass and it works for both. Thanks again.